# The $g$-force of common objects hitting the floor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, collision, estimation

At my friend's work they have an accelerometer which measures the force with which certain objects hit the ground. He claims that from four feet high, cell phones hit a solid metal surface with a $g$-force of over 2000. Is this right? It seems like that number is way too high.

I understand that $g$-force is calculated by (acceleration in m/s<sup>2</sup>)/9.8. I suppose if an object instantly decelerates it would have a very high $g$-force. However, is 2000 a legitimate number? It just seems extremely high.

Comment: Hi Think about the velocity the phone would be when it hit the ground, search newtons equations of motion on wiki. Use those equations to estimate the acceleration (not being smart with you, but acceleration is either plus or minus, no real word such as deceleration in physics). Then divide by g to get g-force. And it will bounce, not stop instantly.  Regards

Comment: as an extension of what @irishphysics is saying, given a number for the acceleration, such as $2000g$, another approach you can do is to estimate the speed with which the thing hits the floor, and then convert that speed, and your known acceleration, into a time of impact.  And then you can convince yourself whether this is reasonable or not.

Comment: This might interest you on you tube, Col John Stapp Takes -47g : https://youtu.be/s4tuvOer_GI

Comment: Thanks for all the info guys. I'm trying to see if I can replicate this programatically via an Android app. I downloaded some off the market but they are only showing up to 4g when I drop my phone on the floor (granted I'm only doing it from 2 feet or my battery pops out, plus I don't wanna ruin my phone). I wrote a little app myself to check my phone's (Galaxy S4) accelerometer and its maximum range is 20m/s^2 with a resolution of 6x10^-4 m/s^2 so I think that should be sufficient to to test this. I'll let you guys know what I come up with!

Comment: I'm sure HTC, Sony, Lumina etc... all test for this type of shock rating, otherwise their stuff wouldn't sell, just wondering what their acceptable limits are...from personal experience tho, it's better than dropping your phone into the bath...no comeback there..sigh...best of luck with the app

Comment: @irishphysics - that Stapp was one crazy dude. Bleeding eyeballs for science. Wow.

Comment: @user3302828 if the internal accelerometer only goes to 20 m/s$^2$ you will just see it clip - and depending on the sampling rate (and associated analog filtering circuitry) you will have a hard time getting an accurate reading of the impact time. Time taken for sound / pressure to travel the length of the phone becomes a potentially significant factor too...

Comment: @Floris  yeah, and all that for what? Nothing they really needed to know or couldn't figure out using a test dummy.  Bit off topic, but this is the last generation of human fighter pilots, drones and their resistance to high g forces are  the future.

Comment: @Floris You're right, the application seems to clip -- the highest g-force I can seem to measure is ~4 g. I am taking the phone`s accelerometer values (for the x,y, and z axes in SI units), and dividing each one by the force of gravity to get a g value. Then I square each value and take a square root of the sum of the squares. This seems accurate as a phone sitting on a flat surface reads 1 g using this method. Unfortunately with the 20 m/s^2 range, I am not sure what else to do. I can take rapid readings (1 every 0.008 seconds). Could this help somehow? Sorry for the noob questions!

Comment: You need to come up with a way to estimate the maximum force - the built in accelerometer is no good for that at the heights you are using. But you could try to drop from very small height (just a few mm) and then scale the result. If you repeat multiple times for some very low heights and plot the result we might have some real data to work with - always better than speculation.

Comment: Ok, so the app was a no go. I was pulling data as fast I could but the results were too inconsistent. I tried dropping it from a height of 1.5 inches and isolating the y-vector, but even that would yield 2.5g on one run and 1.1g on another run. Bottom line I guess is to not use an Android accelerometer for impact testing!

Comment: @floris   one more youtube video   iphone dropped from 100 feet, with a protective cover tho, lands on gravel but I think you may equate this to OP question https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcbyrkzhIXI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**updated calculation**

As a rule of thumb the "g force" of an impact is the ratio of the distance of the fall, and the distance it took to stop falling. This is based on a simple work done argument - $F_1\Delta x_1=F_2\Delta x_2$, and of course $F=m\cdot a$. This approach is the same as used in [this article describing a 'bubble wrap drop' Mythbusters experiment](http://www.decodedscience.com/mythbusters-math-to-compute-g-forces-from-falling/26999). There may be a factor 2 there depending on whether you assume a constant decelerating force (crushing bubble wrap) or an elastic deceleration (where force increases with displacement).

I estimate that when a phone drops on a hard surface, it distorts by about 0.2 mm - based on observation of the small dent on the corner when my wife did in fact drop her phone. But see video below for a much larger distortion...

Taking the ratio $\frac{1200 mm}{0.2 mm}\approx 6000 g$ - meaning that your 2000 g is a reasonable number.

I found a slow motion video of an iPhone breaking - it shows that the distance over which it moves / distorts is significantly greater than I estimated so the g forces will be less:

[image]

[Source of image](http://gearburn.com/2014/09/slow-motion-iphone-6-drop-test-decimates-apples-large-and-bendy-phone/)

When you put your iPhone in a case that provides even a couple of mm of "give" during a drop, the g forces will be much lower and you will improve the chances of surviving a drop on a hard surface very significantly.

Comment: Great answer (would upvote if I could). I learned several things here: 1) The Android accelerometer just isn't useful in this scenario. It wasn't built for crash testing, and even at its fastest data polling, results can be wildly inconsistent. For example -- at 1.5", one drop reading may result in a peak of 2.5g while the next may result in a peak of 1.05g. It`s too inconsistent to use for impact testing. 2) The term 'G force' is a cool sounding term us novices associate with fighter jets, but high g forces can be generated easily by common objects falling insignificant heights.

Comment: Excellent summary! And yes when the time of impact is short compared to the sampling time your results will be highly inconsistent. This is exacerbated by the fact that stress waves bounce around your phone on these time scales. Last time I measured high strain rate events we used a $150k digitizer (with paper tape to store the data... Yes this was before floppy disks!)

Answer (score 0):

using an accelerometer app I saw that dropping you phone onto a blanket only makes the phone hit like 6 to 8 g's and it doesn't cause harm. Humans in fighter jets widthstand these forces also without harm so it makes sense that it would takes thousands of g's to break it.

Comment: Why does it make sense to compare humans and phones?

Comment: Your accelerometer app is likely to include significant filtering (for anti-aliasing) and a rather low sampling rate. Try integrating the area under the curve - then imagine the impact only lasts a fraction of a millisecond, and figure out what peak gives the same integral...